# Ruby Uninitialized Constant Error when Inheriting in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In my LWRP extending a supermarket cookbook, I got the following working.

```
module PIWebsphereCookBook
 class WebsphereJbdc < WebsphereCookBook::WebsphereBase
```

Whereas when I introduced my own class in between these 2, I am getting the '*Unitialized Constant Error*'

```
require_relative './pi_websphere_base'
module PIWebsphereCookBook
  class WebsphereJbdc < PIWebsphereBase
```

The base class I am trying to extend is as shown below:

```
module PIWebsphereCookBook
  class PIWebsphereBase < WebsphereCookbook::WebsphereBase
```

I see from the logs that the referenced class/file is being loaded

```
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Loading cookbook pi_websphere's resources from /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/pi_websphere_base.rb
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/pi_websphere_base.rb into resource pi_websphere_pi_websphere_base (Custom resource pi_websphere_pi_websphere_base from cookbook pi_websphere)
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Loading cookbook pi_websphere's resources from /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_j2c.rb
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Loaded contents of /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_j2c.rb into resource pi_websphere_websphere_j2c (Custom resource pi_websphere_websphere_j2c from cookbook pi_websphere)
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Loading cookbook pi_websphere's resources from /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Filtered backtrace of compile error: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:3:in `<module:PIWebsphereCookBook>',/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:2:in `class_from_file'
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Backtrace entry for compile error: '/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:3:in `<module:PIWebsphereCookBook>''
[2017-06-23T18:37:28-04:00] DEBUG: Line number of compile error: '3'

Recipe Compile Error in 
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb
NameError
---------
uninitialized constant #
<Class:0x000000052796d8>::PIWebsphereCookBook::PIWebsphereBase

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:3:in `    <module:PIWebsphereCookBook>'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:2:in `    class_from_file'

    Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/pi_websphere/resources/websphere_jdbc.rb:
  1:  require_relative './pi_websphere_base'
  2:  module PIWebsphereCookBook
  3>>   class WebsphereJbdc < PIWebsphereBase
  4:      require_relative 'helper'
  5:
```

The folder structure is given below

```
[root@localhost pi_websphere]# tree
.
├── attributes
│   └── default.rb
├── Gemfile
├── jaas_auth.py
├── libraries
│   ├── abc.rb
│   ├── artifactory_helper.rb
│    ├── pi_websphere_base.rb
│   └── websphere_base.rb
├── metadata.rb
├── README.md
├── resources
│   ├── artifactory_client.rb
│   ├── helper.rb
│   ├── websphere_j2c.rb
│   ├── websphere_jdbc.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the file containing `PIWebsphereBase` is loaded first. Normally cookbook library files are loaded in ASCII-betical order, but you can force things a little more with the `require_relative` you have there but is commented out. You probably want `require_relative './pi_websphere_base'` or something like that, or tweak the filenames.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I tried your suggestion as well, please find the updated logs and the code. Thanks again

Comment: sorry. added the complete trace

Comment: Ahh okay, you're putting this under resources/ when it should be libraries/. The resources/ files are for using the custom resource dsl, not raw Ruby.